# Regarding Salesforce merge fields: How can I stop text from wrapping past the original length of the text box, when there is too many characters?

Tags: textbox, salesforce, docusignapi, overlap, contract

I have a few merge fields on a contract that I want to fit between other words in a paragraph. But when the information from Salesforce is too long for the text box it overlaps the following words in the contract, blocking the signers view of those words. I wanted to know if there is any functionality where the text continues but must be clicked on to view. Sort of like a cell in excel?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you login to DocuSign and edit your merge field, you can set it to a fixed width under the 'Formatting' section on the right. This should lock the length of the text field, but it won't allow any more text into the field.